# Show the respective DIV based on ng-if expression. Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to show the div which has `Turn On E-Verify` when clienId has a value if not I want to show the div which has `Turn Off E-verify`. I am not getting any errors but always the second div shows up and the button won't work.  What am I doing wrong?

HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-centered" ng-app="CompanyEVerify">

        <div class="row" ng-controller="EVerifyOptionController">

            <form name="EverifyForm" id="EVerifyForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="EVerifyForm.$valid && submit()"
                  style="background-color: #F0F0F0; border-radius: 8px; padding-top: 10px; margin: 15px !important;">

                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="messages" style="display:none">{{message}}</div>
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="company.Id" />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block">Would you like to opt for  E-Verify feature?</div>

                            <br />
                            <div >                                  

                                <div class="row" ng-if="clientId">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Client ID</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                                            <input type="text" name="clientID" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="clientID" />
                                        </div>

                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-success col-xs-3" ng-click="saveEverifyOption(clientID)">
                                            <i  class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Turn On E-Verify                                          
                                        </button>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" ng-if="!clientId">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Client ID</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                                            <input type="text"  name="clientID" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="clientID" />
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger col-xs-3" ng-click="saveEverifyOption(clientID)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Turn Off E-Verify
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
```

In my controller :

```
$scope.clientId= sessionStorage.clientId;
```

Comment: I assume you wrapped these rows in an ng-repeat or something, can you please share more of the source. Thanks!

Comment: I am not using ng-repeat. It is ony a text box and a button on the page.

Comment: It might be a typo then, I notice you used clientID for ng-model instead of clientId,

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your controller is properly evaluating your conditions. In which case you would use ng-class to bind to css classes. I am not sure If you are trying to hide/show or disable toggle. Going with show/hide, you can make a class:

```
 .hide{
    display:none;
 }
```

On one of your elements:

```
 <button ng-class="{'hide': clientId}" ></button>
```

On the other element:

```
 <button ng-class="{'hide': !clientId}" ></button>
```

Now the hide property on both elements is bound to one single source.

Check out docs [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)